# Stop emails from auto deleting

Tags: email

I have a Samsung note 4.  I have an exchange email set up.  For some reason they auto delete on my phone.  How do I get them to stop auto deleting?  If I log in on the computer they are still there.

Answer (score 0):

By default, setting up an exchange email with your job allows its system administrators to run a distant flash of your phone. Unlink your exchange sync if they can't manage it right